# Sharing Data with Multiple Views - Refactoring

Tags: php, laravel, view

I am looking for a better way to code this. I have been pounding my head into my desk because I just cant seem to figure it out.

I have an application that has multiple companies in it, and each company has their own resources. For example routes would look like this:

test.app/organizations/2/contacts

I have code in the views that rely on the {organization} variable being there. So on every single function I am having to add organization and return it with the view.

I would like to simplify it with like a View::Share or something but the organization doesn't apply to every single view.

This is how it looks now. Is there a better way of doing this? Any guidance would greatly be appreciated!

```
  /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Application|Factory|Response|View
     */
    public function index(Organization $organization)
    {
        return view('app.pages.organization.contact.index', [
            'organization' => $organization
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Return data for datatables.
     *
     */
    public function datatable(Organization $organization)
    {
        $query = $organization->contacts();
        return DataTables::of($query)->toJson();
    }
```

Comment: you can do it in a middleware and add it the the request, you can also have it in the __construct method. you can extend an Organisation controller that uses __construct to populate an attribute organisation. here are other ways. Wich one is better ? depends on how you organise your application.

Comment: @N69S I like that idea but what about returning the organization without having to supply it in each return view function?

Comment: then use the session and have a middleware validate the value and retrieve the Organisation / set it in the session or redirect if missing.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this is what I have figured out after listening to headspace :).

I created a ViewComposer and returned the variable in the specific view composer like this:

```
    protected $organization;

    public function __construct(Organization $organization)
    {
        // Dependencies are automatically resolved by the service container...
        $this->organization = $organization;
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\View\View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('organization', $this->organization);
    }
```

And then in my ViewServiceProvider I specified the pages using a wildcard of what I would like it to apply to. I am surprised I actually got this working. I just hope its the fastest/least resource intensive way of doing it.

```
   public function boot()
   {
       View::composer('app.pages.organization.*', OrganizationComposer::class);
   }
```

Comment: This is okay, is a good solution, I rarely had to use `ViewComposer` but it is super useful when things like this occurs.